# Sticky state doesn't work when applied to a state with params

Tags: javascript, angularjs

sticky state doesn't seem to work when it has parameters.

Example:

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('store', {
            url: '/store',
            abstract: true,
            onEnter: function () {
                //debugger
            },
            templateUrl: helper.basepath('store.html'),

        });
.state('store.products1', {
      url: '/store/:product_id',
      sticky: true
}).state('store.products2', {
      url: '/store/:product_id',
      sticky: true
})
```

my controller is initializes again and again.I not want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the latest version of ui router i.e 0.3.1 but sticky states work with ui router version 0.2.14 and not above version of 0.2.15 and so on.